# Can't run script - error: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: oracle

I have some code that won't run because it expects an INTO clause in the select statement:

```
DECLARE
  StatusCode VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
StatusCode := '';
  SELECT acc.AccountNo,
    acc.AccountTitle,
    NVL(cus.Title,'')     AS Title,
    NVL(cus.Surname,'')   AS Surname,
    NVL(cus.Forename1,'') AS Forename1,
    acc.GBP_Balance,
    CASE
      WHEN sc.ExcludeFromSCV = 1
      THEN 'Yes'
      ELSE 'No'
    END AS ExcludedAccount
  FROM DIM_FM_FSCS_Account acc
  INNER JOIN DIM_FM_FSCS_CustomerAccLink lnk
  ON acc.ID = lnk.FSCSAccountLink
  LEFT JOIN DIM_FM_FSCS_Customer cus
  ON lnk.FSCSCustomerLink = cus.ID
  LEFT JOIN DIM_FM_FSCS_StatusCode sc
  ON (acc.ExclusionCode        = ''
  AND sc.Code                  = acc.AccountStatusCode)
  OR (sc.Code                  = acc.ExclusionCode)
  WHERE (acc.AccountStatusCode = StatusCode
  AND acc.ExclusionCode        = '')
  OR acc.ExclusionCode         = StatusCode;
END;
```

However I am unsure how to add this and how it'll work with this script.

Can I have some help?

Comment: You can have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm)

Answer (score 4):

The error message is clear enough: in PL/SQL you can not make a `SELECT` query without fetching the result into some variable.

For example:

```
SQL> begin
  2      select 1, 2 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /
    select 1, 2 from dual;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: riga 2, colonna 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement


SQL> declare
  2      v1 number;
  3      v2 number;
  4  begin
  5      select 1, 2
  6      into v1, v2
  7      from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So you need to define variable to handle the result(s) of your query.

Notice that in the example I used two scalar variables, but if your query can return more than one row, you will need to use some collection to fetch your data; for example:

```
declare
    type tyListNum is table of number;
    vList1 tyListNum;
    vList2 tyListNum;
begin    
    select 1, 2
    bulk collect into vList1, vList2
    from dual
    connect by level <= 2;
    --
    -- whatever you need to do with the fetched values
end;
```

Comment: I've defined a variable then used that to put INTO but it returns an error ORA00947 saying not enough values

Comment: If your query returns, say 3 columns, you have to use exactly 3 variables or define a type that matches your query result and use a variable of this type.